# What is the meaning of this schematic symbol (labelled COMP.J1 JPAD3)

Tags: stm32

I am trying understand the schematic for a Waveshare Core 407I board, with an STM32F407IGT6 MCu. What is the meaning of this schematic symbol (labelled COMP.J1 JPAD3)?

Link to full schematic: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4a/XCore407I-Schematic.pdf

[image]

I've identified it on the board to be a blob of solder next to a square contact. What component is this if I were to draw it myself in an EDA program?

[image]

Comment: it is similar to a 3 pin header with a push-on jumper

Comment: These are also knows as "solder blob jumpers", unofficially.

Comment: Also, `J` is a common standard identifier for jumpers generally (like `D1` (diode), `R1` (resistor), `L1` (inductor), `Q1` (transistor), `TP1` (test point), `J1` (jumper), etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's known as **solder bridge**.

A solder bridge consists of two, closely-placed SMD pads that can be shorted easily with solder.

The one shown in the question is a 3-terminal solder bridge. Think of it as an SPDT switch. PDR_ON signal is the COMMON terminal. It can be shorted to either +3.3V or GND.

NOTE: Your EDA software (probably Altium) may not have a solder bridge component or equivalent. You may need to build your own.